# Add start and endcolumn with submatch in list

Tags: regex, list, vim, match

My Text:

```
Petro 2013 mytext, 2013, Pimme 2012  2012  2011  2013
```

My Code:

```
let myhits = []
1s/mytext,\s\zs\d\+\ze,\s/\=add(myhits,submatch(0))[-1]/g
```

This code add the **2nd** '2013' in the line to myhits.
Output:

```
myhits = ['2013']
```

My question is:
Is it possible to add the column position of the start and end of every submatch in the list?
Desired output:

```
myhits = ['20-23_2013']
```

Answer (score 1):

I break the logic in lines, if you like, you can pack it in an one-liner:

```
let g:myhits=[]
function! DoIt()

    let s = getline('.')
    let re = 'mytext,\s\zs\d\+\ze,\s'
    let b = match(s,re)
    let m = matchstr(s,re)
    if b>=0 
        call add(g:myhits, b+1 . ('-'. (b+len(m) ).'_'.m))
    endif
endfunction
```

it adds the expected string to the list.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine if there is one match, but what if there are more matches on a line p.e. if `let re = '2013'` ?

Comment: @Remonn you need to write the `re` var by yourself. I just copied your pattern in the codes. If there multi-matches, you need to write a loop, increment the `start` offset, or play with `{count}`. `:h match()` `:h matchstr()`  another tricky way is, use `split()` instead of `match()`, it might save the loop. but I didn't test, jus t an idea. good luck

Comment: I asked in my question for multiple match not for a single match solution ;). Do you think something like this is possible also? `let g:myhits=[] | 1s/2013/\=add(g:myhits,match(submatch(0))[-1].'-'.match(submatch(0))[-1]+len(submatch(0))[-1].'_'.submatch(0))[-1])/g | echo g:myhits`

Comment: @Remonn I don't quite understand your command... why match() has only one argument? IMO, you need the whole line anyway otherwise you cannot calculate the offsets. In your command, I just see `submatch(0)`, how would you do that?

Comment: I don't understand either your solution using a count or split. Please tell me a bit more how to resolve my question. I'm still trying with match() matchlist() matchend()... :((